# How do you determine the PID of a peer TCP connection on the same iOS device?

Tags: c, ios, tcp, sockets

For reasons I'd rather not go into (has to do with compatibility with a third-party library that I cannot change), I need to use a TCP socket to do IPC within a single process in iOS.

In order to prevent other processes from talking to my TCP IPC socket, I'd like to verify with the OS that the process calling `connect()` (from another thread) has the same PID as my own.

On OS X I noticed that `netstat` does not have this information (unlike other OSes such as Windows and Linux) and the only way I was able to determine this information was using `lsof`. I am not sure what might be available in the iOS sandbox, but so far it seems like my best bet (even though it seems expensive) is to figure out what `lsof` is doing and try to replicate that.

Does anyone know of a system call I can use in order to check this? I've already read through `getsockopt(2)` and don't see anything that applies, and I can't find documentation about what `ioctl(2)` calls are supported.

What might be possible here?

Comment: There's no way to do this with sockets API. Can't you use `pipe(2)` instead of creating a socket?

Comment: `socketpair(2)` or `unix(7)` may be a better fits than `pipe(2)`, as they actually behave like sockets.

Comment: Yes, true if you absolutely need that tcp overhead.

Comment: I completely agree with both of you. If I was designing this myself, I'd use a pipe or a local socket. Unfortunately, that's not an option.

Comment: @Mike: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am facing the same problem and you are mine's DenverCoder9 (http://xkcd.com/979/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that sounds like a terrible API for an in-process library.

`getpeername` on the receiving end should match `getsockname` of the sending end.  You could try to match it up with all open fds in the local process.

Comment: Good idea. I thought of doing that, but dismissed the idea because I thought the `struct sockaddr` that gets returned wouldn't be enough. But I forgot that it would probably be a `sockaddr_in` which would contain a `sin_port` field. Now I just need to figure out how to determine which file descriptors are valid. (I suppose brute force could work but I'd rather get a list)

Comment: Best I can come up with so far is to iterate across `getdtablesize()`.

Comment: @Mike: `getdtablesize()` will give you an upper limit to brute-force.  FreeBSD's `fdescfs` can expose file descriptors (usually at `/dev/fd/`), does iOS?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. `/dev/fd/*` is indeed available on OS X, so there's a good chance it will be available on iOS. I'll check.

Comment: @Mike: Double-check that with many open FDs.  Without `fdescfs`, FreeBSD's `devfs` only shows `/dev/fd/[0-2]`.

Comment: Yeah, I see more than `0-2` in there. From `man 4 fd` on OS X: `The files /dev/fd/0 through /dev/fd/# refer to file descriptors which can be accessed through the file system. ...` Looks like it's integrated into devfs.

Comment: Sadly, `/dev/fd` does not exist on iOS. (at least, not that I can open in the iOS sandbox) So I guess it'll have to be the brute force approach.