# Is there a way to find pid of a process of socket peer?

Tags: ios, sockets, iphone-privateapi

I have the following case:

- Two applications (mine and 3rd party) on iOS need to communicate over TCP/IP
- I can change the code of my app, but not the 3rd party app
- The protocol can't be changed (because I can't change the 3rd party app).

In my app, I want to make sure that I talk to the correct app.

I know how I can get peer port with [geetpeername](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html)

What I am looking for is a way to figure out the pid of the process which uses this port.

I found similar question: [How do you determine the PID of a peer TCP connection on the same iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248028/how-do-you-determine-the-pid-of-a-peer-tcp-connection-on-the-same-ios-device#comment23631276_8248028)
However, in his case, both ports are in the same app.

Disclaimer: I am fine with private API. It won't be sent to AppStore. However, I am looking for a solution for non a jailbroken phone.

**Update 1**

I said that I need PID, because there are known ways of getting association between PID and application bundle id (using sysctl).

Generally speaking, I don't care about PID per se. My concern is figure out what is the application on other side of the socket.

Comment: It seems unlikely. How will a PID help? Maybe if you provide more details, we can come up with alternative solution. It seems like the other service would have some type of fingerprint if it didn't actually answer the connection with a known response.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I guess the pid would only help if you could match the process name against the pid, which I'm not sure you can do under iOS, due to sandboxing.  However, I agree, it's very hacky.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I wrote an update.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution for this, but if I was going to try to do it, I would proceed in the following way:

On a UNIX system, you can use the `lsof` command to determine which processes have which files open.  This includes sockets, and `lsof` allows you to determine the pid of a process using a given port.  For example, use

```
lsof -n -P -i :443
```

if you're trying to determine which process is using port 443 (HTTPS), which might yield (on OS X):

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 81615 myname  112u  IPv4 0xffffff8017379a40      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.7:52521->74.125.28.103:443 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

The open source version of `lsof` for Darwin, I believe, [can be found here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/lsof-49/lsof/).  So you might try starting with main.c, and using those command line arguments, navigate through the code until you find the system calls that are used.

It's certainly possible that [the calls needed will not work when run in a process with user mobile privileges](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Port_to_PID).  But, maybe not?  If there's a security check inside the `lsof` source itself, then you can certainly remove that, if you copy and paste the source yourself.

Anyway, it might be worth a try, if no one offers another answer.

**Note:** `lsof` is available for jailbroken phones, and I just tried running the current versions available from Cydia.  They did not work for me, on 5.1.1 or 6.1.2.  Not sure why.  I assume that if they were on the repository, though, at some point, someone was able to port `lsof` to iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found similar info (that I need lsof or netstat). However, the problem that it requires "sudo' to work property on OS X (so my assumption that it won't work on iOS). However, I agree. I need to give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I'm not sure **where** the security check is.  If it's inside the `lsof` code, then you can remove it yourself.  If some system call that `lsof` uses requires root privileges, you might be out of luck.  However, a quick test I run on the desktop suggests that maybe, running `lsof` as `mobile` will simply restrict you to finding out which processes, **run by mobile**, are listening to a given port.  If you're trying to detect another 3rd-party app, then it should also be run by `mobile`.  So maybe it will work for your purposes?